# Match a string with regular expression, starting and ending with specific strings and not containing in between

Tags: c#, regex

Is it possible to match a string between "aa" and dot (.), where matching string doesnt contain "aa"? ie, in string "ab8aabaa8." regex should match "aa8."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Use a negative lookahead:

```
aa(?!.*aa).*\.
```

Comment: it just worked, thanks. btw at the end 8 should be \.  I think.

Comment: Yes, sorry, just got confused by the initial text.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, the matching string does contain aa. In the example, the regex that does the matching is "aa(.+).", and matcher.group(1) would tell you that it matched the string "8" (the syntax depends on the language you are using). I didn't test that RE, but should be easy to test.